# get name from url

Tags: php

I have a function to get domain name from url

```
 <?php
 function getdomain($url)
 {
  $explode = explode(".", $url);
  $tld = $explode[1];
  $tld = explode("/", $tld);
  $name = $explode[1];
  print("$tld[0]");
 }

 print(getdomain("aa.namepros.aaa.com/showthread.php?p=350493"));


?>
```

It works fine for me, but if a user only entered

```
 print(getdomain("namepros"));
```

then, it shows me error.

Comment: It looks like you might want to use http://php.net/parse_url .  I'm not exactly sure what your problem is though?  If the user enters only namepros, should the output be namepros?  Also, print("$tld[0]") is redundant and could be print $tld[0]

Answer (score 3):

You are reinventing the square wheel. This is a common problem, so common that it's been solved ages ago and added to PHP's standard library:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Do yourself a favor and use what's there instead of hurting yourself.

Comment: And the wheel you have at the moment is VERY square :)